# Load the view with pre exisiting data for Editing records before running an update Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the following controller action method.

```
public int BulkUpdate(List<Employee> employees)
         {

           Connection();
           employees = GetAllEmployees().ToList();
            // using reflection, i mean why did i use this ??
            //used it for converting the generic list into datatables.
           DataTable dt = new DataTable(typeof(Employee).Name);
           PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Employee).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
           foreach (var prop in props)
           {
               dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
           }

           foreach (var employee in employees)
           {
               var values = new object[props.Length];
               for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
               {
                   values[i] = props[i].GetValue(employee, null);
               }

               dt.Rows.Add(values);
           }
           //
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BulkUpdateEmployee", con))
           {
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblEmployeeType", dt);
               parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
               parameter.TypeName = "dbo.EmployeeType";


               con.Open();
               var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               con.Close();

               return rowsAffected;
           }//using ends here

       }
and this method is being called in main controller:

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
       public JsonResult BulkUpdateOrInsert(List<Employee> employees)
       {
           int rowsAffected=empRepo.BulkUpdate(employees);
           return Json(rowsAffected, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
```

and this is the View file :

```
    @using System.Collections
    @model IEnumerable<Employee_Management_System.Models.Employee>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "BulkUpdateOrInsert";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function() {
                //Have to Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array maybe try passing it to Controller action.
            var employees = new Array();
                debugger;
                $("#tblEmployees tbody tr").each(function() {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var employee = {};
                employee.Name = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
                employee.City = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
                employee.Department = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
                employee.Gender = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
                employees.push(employee);
            });
        </script>
        @*end of section script*@

        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                    url: "/Employee/BulkUpdateOrInsert",
                    data: JSON.stringify(employees),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                        success: function(r) {
                        alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                }
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>BulkUpdateOrInsert</h2>


        @using (Html.BeginForm("BulkUpdateOrInsert", "Employee", "POST"))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


            <h4>Employee</h4>
            <hr />

            <table class="table" id="tblEmployees">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.City)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Department)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.EmployeeId}) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.EmployeeId}) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.EmployeeId})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                }

            </table>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save All" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
            @section Scripts {
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            }
        }
    </body>

    </html>
```

The problem is that the view is not loaded for Updating the records.
My requirement is to load the view with pre-existing data in SQL Server database.
Edit the records using `HTML.EditFor`, return the Generic List of Updated Records --> Convert them to DataTable, and pass that datatable to stored procedure. (this I have taken). The problem is I am not able to load the view to update entries in database. Directly the stored procedure is getting executed before the view is loaded.

Stored Procedure:

```
USE EMPLOYEE_Db
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkUpdateEmployee]
@tblEmployeeType [dbo].[EmployeeType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE
SET
Employee.Name=et.Name,
Employee.City=et.City,
Employee.Department=et.Department,
Employee.Gender=et.Gender

FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN @tblEmployeeType AS et
ON dbo.EMPLOYEE.EmployeeId=et.EmployeeId    

END
```

Answer (score 0):

**- The problem is that the view is not loaded for Updating the records**
There is no code which loads data from database into your view. You need to have a GET Action in controller which loads required data and returns the view.

Comment: so i have a controller method now just to load the data in editable format.Now the question is how do i save the tabular data and redirect it to another page.